# Outlook: Flagged emails getting overdue within a minute getting red

Tags: microsoft-outlook, tasks

I always used to flag emails for the followup in outlook for later in the day. I try to finish all the task in task list before end of the before they get overdue and turn red.

From past 2-3 days, I am not sure what changed, when I am marking any mails to follow up, it is turning red in a minute or so.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thanks for making it right. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the fix for this issue, it i something to do with the Microsoft TODO app.

ALL you need to do is:

- Install Microsoft todo app from app store
- Connect it with your account office/home
- Go to settings of the app -> Connections
- Uncheck flagged email.
- It will ask that the messages will be deleted say yes(It wont delete the actual email)
- Voila issue is fixed!!

Answer (score 0):

The more you click the flag, it will change features of the flag, ie due dates, today, tomorrow, next week...  Also if its a group email others can click the flags too, and whomever sent it can also adjust the flag, but you can re-adjust it...

Comment: I am clicking on the flag once  only, first it comes to my task lists then within just minutes it turns ovrdue. Which is annoying.

Comment: Have you checked the due date of these tasks?

Comment: @Perry I checked the due date of the tasks, it is getting changed to previous day automatically. When I am marking email for today for few seconds it shows that it is due today, then automatically it is getting due for yesterday.